# Sql server 2005 with ASP .NET encoding issue

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server, encoding, utf-16

I'm writing once again about my encoding issue... Now with some code samples.

In a nutshell: when saving to database input data, some language specyfic characters like polish 'ń' won't save - insted 'n' is saved. On the other hand, string: Adams æbler, with æ is saving.

Here is code begind code that does save stuff and displays data:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["encoding"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users";
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Label1.Text += reader.GetString(0);
            }                
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["encoding"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('" + Surname.Text + "')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }  
    }
```

Default.aspx has meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]([Surname] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NULL ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I don't know what else is needed to solve the issue. Help appreciated.

Thanks, Paweł

Comment: Ah, when I issued: SELECT Surname, CAST(Surname AS VARBINARY(30)) AS Expr1 FROM Users, bytes for alledged 'ń' character are 0x6E00 - so in database 'n' character is stored.

Comment: Does `Surnme.Text` contain the correct value if you debug in `Button1_Click`? What value appears to be sent to SQL Server if you use SQL Profiler?

Comment: Yes. Surname.Text has correct value. Also checking it with Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes returns "good" bytes. I haven't checked it with profiler yet.

Comment: And profiled checked: INSERT INTO users VALUES('ń') was sent...

Comment: I thought this question looked familiar.  I just saw your other question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I figured out what is wrong. I missed N prefix before string (it marks string as UNICODE):

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO users VALUES(N'" + Surname.Text + "')";
```

Thanks,
Paweł

Answer (score 1):

Your table definition appears to be the problem.  Surname is defined with `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI`.  The `AI` part indicates Accent Insensitive.  You would need to change the collation to Latin1_General_CI_AS, to preserve the data.